# Search curl output for string with Bash

Tags: regex, bash

Trying to fetch a webpage as a lowercase string, then search the string output for a substring

My attempt:

```
  1 #!/usr/bin/env bash
  2
  3 URL="https://somesite.com"
  4 MOVIES_SOURCE="movies.txt"
  5 PAGE=`curl "$URL"` | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
  6
  7 while IFS= read -r movie
  8 do
  9   FOUND="$($PAGE =~ "$movie")"
 10   echo $FOUND
 11   if [[ $FOUND ]]; then
 12    echo "$movie found"
 13   fi
 14 done < $MOVIES_SOURCE
 15
```

When I run this, I'm receiving `line 9: =~: command not found`

The `$movie` variable is valid and contains each line from `movies.txt`, but I'm struggling to figure out this one!

Comment: Use the `~` operator inside `[[..]]`

Comment: Adding the line numbers makes it more difficult to copy and test your code, by the way.

Comment: I'm a bit unclear about what you're trying to do...some sample input and corresponding desired output would make things clearer. I suspect that this can be reduced to a short line of awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use regex matching in bash:

```
if [[ $PAGE =~ $movie ]]; then
    echo "$movie found"
fi
```

example:

```
PAGE="text blah Avengers more text"
movie="Avengers"
if [[ $PAGE =~ $movie ]]; then
    echo "$movie found"
fi
```

gives:

```
Avengers found
```

**Also:** to capture the output of the whole curl command:

```
PAGE=$(curl "$URL" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
```

- always prefer `$()` over backticks
- you had to wrap your whole command in order for `$PAGE` to contain the output where you converted to lowercase.